# breakable tcolorbox is eating my minipage

Tags: tcolorbox, minipage, layout

I have a memoir document full of `minipages` and breakable `tcoloboxes` and I don't understand the interaction between the two. Sometimes my minipage contents gets pushed far beyond the bottom of the actual page. I put together a MWE below, where the blue rectangle is not shown in full. As per comments below, the problem is more with `tcolorbox` than memoir, but still it remains mysterious to me.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\begin{minipage}{10cm}
  \color{blue}\rule{2cm}{16cm}

  O brother were art thou ?
\end{minipage}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable=true]
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

edit: add a screenshot of the result[image: a screenshot of the result]

Comment: it breaks in the book class too.  It works in article as it uses \raggedbottom. The main problem is that your box has a large depth. You could use `\begin{minipage}[b] `

Comment: actually in my real use-case I found other workarounds too. But still I remain curious: what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think that you are doing something wrong. The tcolorbox starts on page 1 and then does lots of magic to decide if it can split or not and this seems to confuse the page builder. Open an issue at tcolorbox github. Perhaps the maintainer can do something.

Comment: Might want to change the title and remove the `memoir` tag as it is not `memoir` related

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Here is the github issue: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/200 Let's wait and see

Comment: @Gyom an extract of the answer by the maintainer -- `A breakable tcolorbox inserts the code given by the before option and then calculates the remaining height of the page. If the height is not large enough, as in your example, tcolorbox tries to undo inserted spacing during before and afterwards inserts a \pagebreak.`

`Apparently, the undoing in your case gives unexpected results. The reason is the large depth of your minipage, because \prevdepth is taken into account for the undoing process. Using \begin{minipage}[b] would circumvent the problem.`